# Remote access to matlab from windows computer to mac

Tags: vnc, remote-access, matlab

first of all I must say: please be patient with me(!)

I work with matlab in my university. Lately I have being working with very heavy codes and my computer is not powerful enough. A professor, and friend of my, who lives in another city is allowing me to use his computer, much more powerful than mine. My question is:

How can I remotely connect to his computer and run matlab from mine? In other word, how can I write, and debug codes in my windows computer but using his processor? Hi has a mac computer.

What I have tried: I have downloaded VNC server and installed it. But I dont know how to proceed. Given the fact that I actually need VNC...?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For VNC access I have used [RealVNC](https://www.realvnc.com/) wich is very easy to setup and use. Install the server on the destination computer and a client on your own. I think you have to buy the software, but it is relatively inexpensive.

There are other options such as http://www.teamviewer.com/ or others wich can be used (to some extend) for free.

A thing to be aware of when using Matlab remotely is the risk of writing code that will put too heavy a load on the server. If the load is too great you can loose connection to the server until the Matlab-script is done (if it is not in an infinite loop of another endless programming error).